# onKeyDown prevents hardware volume buttons to work

Tags: java, android

When a user presses the back button in Android, I have a customDialog asking "Are you sure". The problem is that if I implement the onKeyDown method, the volume hard buttons just don't work and the volume doesn't go up or down (in the whole Activity).

I don't understand why since I'm only checking for KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK.

```
  @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
       //CustomDialog code
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: Where are you returning `false`?

Comment: That was the issue, replacing true by false solved it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get a callback when the user clicked back button in an activity it's better to use `onBackPressed`